# How to Edit Layout Update Xml for CMS Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, cms, magento2-migration-tool, cms-pages

I just migrated from Magento **1.9.3.4 to Magento 2.3.4**, I noticed some of the page content is missing when I accessed the page that was created from cms page.

Then I look at the cms page edit page, in M1 I can update the Page layout XML like this:

[image]

But in M2 I can't find this section:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was removed in Magento 2.3.4 due to a vulnerability which allowed admin users to execute code via the custom layout field. There is more info about it [in this blog post](https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magento-2-3-4-custom-layout-updates).

The solution is now to manage this with XML files in the codebase, the file name must be in this format - `catalog_category_view_selectable_<Category ID>_<Layout Update Name>.xml`

See the [official dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-layouts) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the information, if I have a cms page with `about-us` as a page identifier, where should i define the layout XML ? `Magento_Theme/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_about-us_???`  ??

Answer (score 0):

That's great to know, you've migrated your store from M1 to M2, Please check out this [Magento official DevDoc](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/page-add.html).

Besides, this functionality has been removed in 2.3.4